# Different Method For a Calculator Using Multiple Boolean Types

Tags: java, if-statement, calculator, boolean-logic

I tried to create a calculator using multiple boolean types on one "if" command. I also tried to use the numbers **42(*),43(+),45(-) and 47(/)** from the ASCII table instead of the symbols. Now, for some resson it's not working both with the numbers and the symbols and I would like to know why. I know how to solve the problem using **different methods** but i want to understand the logic of why my programm isn't working, thanks for anyone who can help!

One of the different methods:
[[Trouble with a simple calculator code (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33403299/trouble-with-a-simple-calculator-code-java][1])

```
    package RemoteSystemsTempFiles;

    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class SecondLesson2 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {


        System.out.println("Print an equation with +,-,*,/");
        Scanner reader=new Scanner(System.in);
         double num5=reader.nextDouble();
         char action=reader.next().charAt(0);
         double num6=reader.nextDouble();
         if (action=='+' || action=='-' || action=='*' || action=='/')
         {
             System.out.println(num5+action+num6+"=");
         }
         else System.out.println("You haven't printed it correctly");
        }

    }
```

Comment: The mistake is with the formation of the String. You attempt to form a String from two doubles and a character which performs numerical calculation as opposed to String concatenation.  System.out.println(num5 + "" + action + "" + num6 + "="); resolves this.

Comment: Thank you Zachary, but i have one more question, how can i write the solution of the String without using "if" multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original problem is with the line `System.out.println(num5+action+num6+"=");` where you attempt to form a String from 2 doubles and a character. This will perform numeric calculation before casting to a String. To concatenate to form a String, you can simply use `System.out.println(num5 + "" + action + "" + num6 + "" + "=");`

You also asked if there is a better way to solve the equation without a tone of if-statements - Not very elegantly unfortunately. You can use a switch statement to make it somewhat more legible, such as below. There is a JavaScript [ScriptEngine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html) library for Java you may be interested in, but if you know what the inputs will be the Switch statement is as good as you will get.

```
public static double doOperation (double x, double y, char op) {
    switch (op) {
        case '+': return x + y;
        case '-': return x - y;
        case '/': return x/y;
        case '*': return x*y;
    }
    return 0;
}
```